# How to call a base function from a derived object and not alter the variable assignments in the Base contract and other Derived objects

Tags: solidity, inheritance, function-override

Our base function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20{
    address private m_owner;

    uint256 private m_delay = 1 days;

    mapping(address => uint256) private lockTime;

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol){
        m_owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function faucet(address to, uint256 amount) external virtual{
        require(block.timestamp > lockTime[msg.sender], "lock time has not ended");

        _mint(to, amount);

        lockTime[to] = block.timestamp + m_delay; 
    }

    function setDelay(uint256 time) public virtual{
        m_delay = time;
    }

    function setOwner(address account) public virtual{
        m_owner = account;
    }
}
```

Our Derived class:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Token.sol";
contract Dai is Token{
    
    constructor() Token("Dai", "DAI") {
    }
}
```

How would I be able to use faucet() and setOwner() for the Dai contract specifically to set the value for Dai contract. Would I need to create it's own faucet() and setOwner()?? If yes, then there would be no use of making a base Token class?

Such as if I were to do

```
Dai d = new Dai();
dai.faucet(msg.sender, 1 ether);
dai.setOwner(address(0));
```

I believe it would not work as stated. It would set the Owner of Token contract instead. Which wouldn't be so useful as if I were to create multiple Token derived contracts, every time I set the owner for that specific contract, it'd change the owner for the base class instead.

How do I alter the Dai contract so it changes specifically for Dai contract while not affecting other derived contracts.

Comment: Such things you don't need to believe, you can check. For example go to any environment such as RemixIDE, create 2 tokens that inherit the same contract, call .setOwner and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In solidity inheritance works slightly different than other languages.

Let's suppose you have a Base contract and a Derived contract.

```
contract Base {
    uint256 public x;

    function foo(uint256 a) public {
        x = 1000 + a;
    }

    function bar() public view returns (uint256) {
        return x;
    }
}

contract Derived is Base {
    function bar() public view returns (uint256) {
        return 123 + super.bar();
    }
}
```

When Derived is compiled the resulting bytecode will be similar to DerivedFlattened:

```
contract DerivedFlattened {
    uint256 public x;

    function foo(uint256 a) public {
        x = 1000 + a;
    }

    function Base_bar() internal view returns (uint256) {
        return x;
    }

    function bar() public view returns (uint256) {
        return 123 + Base_bar();
    }
}
```